# How to combine Amazon credentials with Facebook credentials in settings.json

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, facebook-login

I am trying to setup my settings.json file in the correct way but I can't seem to get it to work.

I currently have my Amazon S3 credentials saved in the file but when I want to add Weibo or FB credentials my app keeps crashing.

What is the correct way to add several services?

At the moment it looks like this:

```html
{
 "AWSAccessKeyId": "Amazon key",
 "AWSSecretAccessKey": "Amazon secret"
}
```

I need to add the following:

```html
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
  { service: "weibo" },
  {
    $set: {
      clientId: "1292962797",
      loginStyle: "popup",
      secret: "75a730b58f5691de5522789070c319bc"
    }
  }
);
```

And the same goes for the FB credentials. What is the correct way to combine all of these in 1 file?

When I setup my file as suggested below I get this error: Error: Match error: Missing key 'AWSAccessKeyId'

This is my settings.json setup at the moment:

```html
{
  "public": {

  },
  "private": {
    "facebook": {
      "appId": "FBId",
      "secret": "FBsecret"
    },
    "weibo": {
      "clientId": "WeiboId",
      "secret": "WeiboSecret"
    },
    "aws": {
      "bucket": "ec2016",
      "AWSAccessKeyId": "S3Id",
      "AWSSecretAccessKey": "S3Secret",
      "region": "eu-central-1"
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Following the help I received here I set up my setting.json file and another file on the server called configure-services. It looks like this. After fixing a typo (Duh...) it now all works! Thanks so much!

```js
const p = Meteor.settings.private;

const faceAppId = p.facebook.appId;
const faceSecret = p.facebook.secret;

const S3KeyId = p.aws.key;
const S3AccessKey = p.aws.secret;

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({
  service: 'facebook'
}, {
  $set: {
    service: 'facebook',
    appId: faceAppId,
    secret: faceSecret,
  },
});

Slingshot.fileRestrictions("myImageUpload", {
  allowedFileTypes: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "video/mp4", "video/avi", ],
  maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // 10 MB (use null for unlimited)
});

Slingshot.createDirective('myImageUpload', Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  bucket: p.aws.bucket,
  region: p.aws.region,
  AWSAccessKeyId: S3KeyId,
  AWSSecretAccessKey: S3AccessKey,
  acl: 'public-read',

  authorize: function () {
    //Deny uploads if user is not logged in.
    if (!this.userId) {
      var message = "Please login before posting files";
      throw new Meteor.Error("Login Required", message);
    }
    return true;
  },

  key: function (file) {
    //Store file into a directory by the user's username.
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    return user.username + "/" + file.name;
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean your app is crashing? Can you paste the error?

Comment: Ow yes sorry, 

So when I try to combine the two (I just copy paste the second code under the first one) I get this error:

settings-development.json: parse error reading settings file

Comment: It does work if I only have the Amazon S3 information in the file btw.

Comment: I think this might be a JSON issue. Can you post the JSON file you would use with all the services?

Comment: I did, can you check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the format I usually for `settings.json` file:

```
{
  "public": {

  },
  "private": {
    "facebook": {
      "namespace": "",
      "appId": "",
      "secret": ""
    },
    "google": {
      "clientId": "",
      "secret": ""
    },
    "aws": {
      "bucket": "",
      "key": "",
      "secret": "",
      "region": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Then use them as follow:

```
const p = Meteor.settings.private;

const faceAppId = p.facebook.appId;
const faceSecret = p.facebook.secret;

const ggClientId = p.google.clientId;
const ggSecret = p.google.secret;

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({
  service: 'facebook'
}, {
  $set: {
    service: 'facebook',
    appId: faceAppId,
    secret: faceSecret,
  }
});


ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({
  service: 'google'
}, {
  $set: {
    service: 'google',
    clientId: ggClientId,
    secret: ggSecret,
  }
});

Slingshot.createDirective('imageUpload', Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  bucket: p.aws.bucket,
  region: p.aws.region,
  AWSAccessKeyId: p.aws.key,
  AWSSecretAccessKey: p.aws.secret,
  acl: 'public-read',
  maxSize: 20 * 1024 * 1024,
  allowedFileTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'],
  authorize: function() {
    // ...
  },
  key: function() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: When I add the settings.json file like this I get the following error: 
Error: Match error: Missing key 'AWSAccessKeyId'

I am using edgee_slingshot to upload my files to my Amazon S3 server. I have also already tried renaming the ClientId and secret in the format you just supplied. 

Any other ideas?

Comment: I still didn't manage to get the two working, any other ideas?

Comment: @Deelux I added way to create Slingshot directive, hope it helps

Comment: Great, going to try it out! Thanks so much for taking the time to write this.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I am doing something wrong. I am still getting this error:
Error: Match error: Missing key 'AWSAccessKeyId' 

I put the file on the server side, and don't import anything in the file right? Or should I import settings.json in here? I believe this is done automaticly right?

Comment: I think I'm getting closer :-) 
I moved my file to be sure it gets loaded on the server. Now I am getting a specific slingshot error so I think it's working.
Error: Match error: Missing key 'authorize'

Comment: Thnk a lot for your reply